# MySQL Table row for every 30 minute

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a table with all the row rappresenting half an hour within 08:00:00 and 20:00:00.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE cal (
    id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    month                   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    day                     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    half                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    hour                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    checked         TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0, -- Check if is reserved 
   ) Engine = MyISAM;
```

and my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN giorno DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    DECLARE stoppete DATE;
    SET currentdate =  '08:00:00';
    SET stoppete = '20:00:00';
    WHILE currentdate < stoppete DO
        INSERT INTO cal VALUES (
            concat(DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%m'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%d'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%H'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%i')),
            DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%Y'),
            DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%m'),
            DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%d'),
            DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%i'),
            DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%H'),
            0);
        SET currentdate = DATE_ADD(currentdate,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
    END WHILE;
END
```

But when I try to call fill_date_dimension('2017-05-30') it never populate the table.

I think the problem is the while loop and mysql can't loop within hours but only day.

Comment: with the `set currentdate` you replace the entire contents of the datevalue (2017-05-30) with '08:00:00'. What happens if you remove the line `set currentdate` and change the `set stoppete` with `SET stoppete = '2017-05-30 20:00:00';

Comment: a faster option to test would be to remove the lines `set currentdate` and `set stoppete` to test if it works like that, after that you could limit accordingly (from 8 am to 8 pm)

Comment: don't forget you missed a `,` before the `0` and check the amount of fields you're trying to insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have multiple problems:

1. you missed a comma (you already addressed that after the update
2. with the lines `SET currentdate =  '08:00:00';` and `SET stoppete = '20:00:00';` you replace the date you enter with only the time.
3. the amount of fields you're trying to insert don't correspond

This insert query:

```
INSERT INTO cal VALUES (
        concat(DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%m'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%d'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%H'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%i')),
        DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%Y'),
        DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%m'),
        DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%d'),
        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%i'),
        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%H'),
        0);
```

will insert 7 fields, usually skipping the id field. The concat part will tried to be inserted into the year field, not the id field.

Try an explicit query:

```
INSERT INTO cal (id,year,month,day,half,hour,checked) VALUES (
        concat(DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%m'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%d'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%H'),DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%i')),
        DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%Y'),
        DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%m'),
        DATE_FORMAT(giorno, '%d'),
        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%i'),
        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate, '%H'),
        0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

1. '08:00:00' is not valid date value (use datetime and combine the giorno with date)
2. id-column is defined as integer and your values are most likely out of range